# How junit's BeforeClass annotation behaves in a top level object in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, junit, annotations, singleton

I have a beginner's question:
I have a spark based scala project that uses junit.
This is the important part of the project:

```
object ResearchCrawlServiceTestSuite {
  implicit var ss: SparkSession = _
  var fs: FileSystem = _


  @BeforeClass
  def init(): Unit = {
    ss = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
    fs = get(ss.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  }
}

class ResearchCrawlServiceTestSuite {
  self =>
  private object testImplicits extends SQLImplicits {
    protected override def _sqlContext: SQLContext = self.ss.sqlContext
  }

  import testImplicits._

  implicit val ss: SparkSession = ResearchCrawlServiceTestSuite.ss
  val fs: FileSystem = ResearchCrawlServiceTestSuite.fs

  @Test def submitCrawlSanity() {
    val seeds = (0 to 4).map(i => s"www.$i.com").toDF("url")
    ...
   }
}
```

If I change the object's name to be different than the class below it, it seems that the @BeforeClass method wont run.
My question is, when does the @BeforeClass annotation run?
how it behaves inside a top -level object which is not a companion object?
how it behaves inside a top -level object which is a companion object?
how it behaves inside a nested object?